# App Service VNet Integration with Azure Storage Service Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-virtual-network

I made an App Service (S1) and then from the Networking blade created a VNet Integration using the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#creating-a-pre-configured-vnet). The connection looks like [image: VNet Integration Configuration]
Then I made a Storage Account and under the Firewall and Networking tab I selected the preconfigured VNet that was made by the portal [image: Storage networking tab here]

Trying to access the Azure Storage from a deployed Web App give a 403 forbidden error. What settings do I need to change for the Web App to gain access to the Azure Storage Service Endpoint?

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Outside of using App Service Environment, it looks like Virtual Networks are not possible. But Azure AD Authentication for Azure Storage is in preview and may be something you could look into to lock down azure storage resources.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-preview-of-aad-authentication-for-storage/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vnet integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network but **does not** grant private access to your web app from the virtual network.

> Private site access refers to making your app only accessible from a
>   private network such as from within an Azure virtual network. Private
>   site access is **only available** with an **ASE** configured with an Internal
>   Load Balancer (ILB).

More information about ILB ASE, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase).

Comment: "Vnet integration gives your web app access to resources in your virtual network" is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: @robjam yes, you are use vnet integration, but it does not work for Azure storage.

Comment: @robjam Yes, vnet integration not work for service endpoints.

Comment: @robjam Please try to use ASE and service endpoint to achieve it.

Comment: This is not true, the New VNET Integration works already with SQL Server and CosmosDb without needing an ASE. So one would expect Azure Storage to be added to the list as well. However, Azure Storage does not work in this setup at the moment.