# Azure WebApp and AzureSQL in VNET

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-network

I want to do the following:

One Azure WebApp
One AzureSQL

And I want to restrict access to the AzureSQL only for the WebApp.
So I have done the following:
1) Create WebApp

2) Create AzureSQL

3) Create VNET with subnet and Gateway. So my VNET has to subnets.

4) On my WebApp unter "Networking" I selected "connect to my VNET"

5) In the gateway I see "Connection: 1"

6) In the SQL Server under Firewall I turnes "Access from Azure" to "OFF" and 
added unter VNET my VNET (default subnet) and enabled "Service endpoint".

7) now I've one index.php in my WebApp with the following:

```
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
```

But this fails. When I turn on the option "Allow Azure" in the SQL Server everything works. But I want to only have access from my WebApp.

So what I am doing wrong? Do you need more infos?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you have a WebApp connect to a Vnet, it just grants WebApp access the resources in the vnet, Similarly, when you have a SQL server attached to a Vnet. It grants the SQL server interactive with resources in the vnet. In this case, there is no way to restrict that only webapp can access the SQL server.

However, [ASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) can achieve your purpose. ASE feature can provide a fully isolated and dedicated environment for securely running App Service apps at high scale.

Here is a similar case: [How to secure access from App Service To Azure Sql Database using virtual network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50483132/how-to-secure-access-from-app-service-to-azure-sql-database-using-virtual-networ/50483574#50483574)